# Silverlight MVVM in VS2008 - a non starter?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I'm still very new to Silverlight. I'm currently using vs2008 at work.
As far as I can gather Silverlight 4 is vs2010 only.
I stumbled across [this article on command binding](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article859-command-binding-in-silverlight-4-stepbystep-.aspx), it says that command binding is 
a new feature introduced in silverlight 4.
Is command binding integral to MVVM in silverlight, does it make MVVM much simpler to implement?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Commanding does make MVVM much easier, but it's also very easy to provide your own reusable commanding infrastructure.  Attached Behaviors give you an easy way to right up a generic way to attach a Command to events.

I while back I wrote a very generic behavior that provides three properties: Command, CommandParameter, and EventName.  It then uses reflection to wire up EventName and whene that event gets thrown it calls the Command.  It's a very simple solution and is actually much more flexible than the direct commands on the SL4 controls, because you can attach to any event you like.

Comment: Also checkout http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted/#tutorials, EventToCommand behavior for a framework that does what Stephan suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Any XAML work in VS 2008 is a non-starter. The IDE is just too slow and buggy.

Comment: What bugs are you refering to?  It is true VS2010 is faster but speed is a function of your hardware.

Comment: This probably is easily solved by using the XML editor instead.  You still get Intellisense, but it runs significantly faster.

Comment: I regularly crash VS 2008 when I touch XAML files. Like Stephan, the only way I can keep it stable is to only edit XAML as straight XML.